# Why Realm throwing Realm accessed from incorrect thread, when the whole operation is executed on the same Thread

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, realm, realm-mobile-platform

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    ShowCaseInfo existingShowcase = DBService.GetDB().FetchShowcaseInfo();
                    string previousResponse = existingShowcase?.SerializedResponse;
                    Response response = await CloudService.GetCloudService().FetchShowcase();

                    if (response.Status == ResponseStatus.SUCCESS && !string.Equals(previousResponse, response.Data))
                    {
                        ShowCaseInfo showcaseInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ShowCaseInfo>(response.Data, _settings);
                        showcaseInfo.SerializedResponse = response.Data;
                        DBService.GetDB().InsertOrUpdateShowcase(showcaseInfo);
                        FetchShowcaseProducts(showcaseInfo.Showcases);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<Showcase> emptyCases = new List<Showcase>();
                            if (existingShowcase != null)
                            {
                                foreach (Showcase showcase in existingShowcase.Showcases)
                                {
                                    if (showcase.Products.Count == 0)
                                    {
                                        emptyCases.Add(showcase);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        FetchShowcaseProducts(emptyCases);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            });
```

foreach (Showcase showcase in existingShowcase.Showcases) line is throwing the exception. Similarly, in the if condition !string.Equals(previousResponse, response.Data), instead of a local variable had I accessed the previousResponse as existingShowcase.SerializedResponse, some exception was thrown. As per the doc, we are not supposed to pass the object across threads, but in this case all the operations are within the same thread.

Answer (score 2):

> in this case all the operations are within the same thread.

No, they're actually not. This is because of how `await` works.

[When `await` acts asynchronously, it captures its current context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) - either `SynchronizationContext.Current` or `TaskScheduler.Current`. In this case, the context is the thread pool context. So, when the method resumes executing after the `await`, it may resume executing on *any* thread pool thread.

Answer (score 2):

As Stephen said in his answer, `await` will not return to the original calling thread in its continuation unless there is a `SychronizationContext` on the original thread. When using `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`, the worker thread won't have a `SychronizationContext` by default. The `Nito.AsyncEx` package (which is actually written by Stephen) provides the `AsyncContext` class which can be used inside a `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` delegate, and any `Task`s which are `await`ed inside the delegate passed to `AsyncContext.Run` will continue on the same thread unless `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is used.

https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/AsyncContext.md

To make this easier in the context of Realm, I created a simple extension method to allow asynchronous background-thread work to be done to a Realm database:

```csharp
public static Task RunTask(this Realm realm, Func<Realm, Task> workFunction) => Task.Run(() => AsyncContext.Run(async () => {
    using var workerRealm = await Realm.GetInstanceAsync(realm.Config);

    await workFunction(workerRealm);
}));

public static Task<TResult> RunTask<TResult>(this Realm realm, Func<Realm, Task<TResult>> workFunction) => Task.Run(() => AsyncContext.Run(async () => {
    using var workerRealm = await Realm.GetInstanceAsync(realm.Config);

    return await workFunction(workerRealm);
}));
```

In my app I usually have a handle to the UI thread's Realm instance somewhere, so if I ever need to do expensive background work, I just use `whateverRealm.RunTask(async backgroundRealm => /* some work with awaits in it */`. The `backgroundRealm` parameter passed into the delegate will be safe to use anywhere inside the delegate so long as `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is not called on any tasks being `await`ed.